# Percentage Widths & 1px Borders

Tags: html, css

I've noticed in both current versions of Safari and Chrome that when I create elements side by side, rounding up to a whole 100% number, I get an adjusting small pixel border (since I'm not using a white background for the elements/divs) that resizes.  I feel like I'm simply missing a position attribute, but I can't find any resources on el Google to help me out.

A fiddle to illustrate my problem (OS X Safari & Chrome tested)

http://jsfiddle.net/shawnstrickland/HXyZ7/

Comment: That is odd, not seen it before. Also applies to non HTML5 elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/HXyZ7/2/

Comment: FWIW, looks fine on Chrome Ubuntu.

Comment: @nickf Gotta love consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `overflow:hidden;`. write like this:

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}
article {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: red;   
}
```

​

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/HXyZ7/7/

Answer (score 1):

The white gap vanishes as i increase it to 75.3 :p

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}
article {
    float: right;
    clear:none;
    background-color: red;
    width: 75.3%;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJQeZ/
​

Answer (score 1):

Webkit has problems calculating percentage values.

http://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit/

Answer (score 0):

You use the whole witdh, but your floating options create this issue.
Use only one floating direction (left here).

Unfortunately I don't know WHY this happens.

**Edited sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/HXyZ7/1/

```
nav {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: blue;
}
article {
    float: left; /* was floating right before */
    background-color: red;
    width: 75%;   
}
```

Comment: This is true, but look closely, the gap is still visible on the right of the Article element.